# Deleting the specific data element in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to be able to delete a specific data-element on a click of its corresponding button.
I'm printing the data out on my page along with the respective delete buttons with `ng-repeat`.
My data structure is this. 
[image]

To delete, I believe I'll have to access that data first.
I can access the data objects till 'contents' (in the above data tree) with following code but somehow I cannot dynamically access the elements after that.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://url.firebaseio.com/resto/menu");
var fbref = $firebase(ref);
var refArr= fbref.$asArray();
$scope.datas = refArr;
$scope.removeItem = function (e) {
    console.log(e); //Prints category name, Drinks, maincourse etc.
    var drilledDown = ref.child(e).child('content'); //url.firebaseio.com/resto/menu/'category'/content 
};
```

If at all I'm structuring my data wrong, I'd like insights on that too please.

Comment: The AngularFire tutorial has this snippet for deleting an item from an array: `<button ng-click="messages.$remove(message)">X</button>`. So don't create your own method, just let the AngulareFire array handle it. (see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)

Comment: That worked for me on the first level of my data. But when I do this : `<span ng-init="contents = data.content">
<span ng-repeat="product in contents">
<button ng-click="contents.$remove(product)">Delete</button>` It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?